# Hibernate hbm xml mapping of non-existing property

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hbm

Is it possible to use non-existing property in Hibernate xml mapping?

```
<property name="nonExisting" type="java.lang.String" column="nonExisting"/>
```

So I can have `nonExisting` column in my DB, but not in my class. I also need to use Hibernate criteria with that column.

Answer (score 0):

you can write named query in xml file:

EXP:

```
<sql-query name="named.query" >
    <return alias="b" class="com.classes.ClassName"/>

select col1 as {b.p1},col2 as {b.p2}
from db_table_name tab where tab.nonExisting = xxxxx

</sql-query>
```

p1 and p2 variable in your class. col1 and col2 column in your table.